# How To Determine If An Application Is Running or Not?

Tags: android, function

I have to run some background tasks whenever an application is activated / or starts running. Suppose u r running the application and then suddenly the device got off or any how u got out of the application without stopping it properly, then when you will again start the application, obviously it will start running from the previous state before getting out of the application. When it starts again or activated, i want my background tasks to be done.Is there any function which is called every time an application starts which i can use to initialize those background tasks? If not then how can i accomplish my purpose? Need help on this , Thanks in advance .... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an application returns from being in the background, at very least it will run the the `onResume()` function:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    //You have to call super.onResume(), otherwise an exception is thrown
    super.onResume();

    // and then do whatever you want here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the main activity class's `OnCreate` method is called whenever an application is started.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) -

> Called when the activity is starting. This is where most initialization should go: calling setContentView(int) to inflate the activity's UI, using findViewById(int) to programmatically interact with widgets in the UI, calling managedQuery(android.net.Uri, String[], String, String[], String) to retrieve cursors for data being displayed, etc.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799819/android-application-launch-count) question might be helpful. From the accepted answer -

> OnCreate is called regardless of you start the app or you resume the app.

Comment: Well , you are right that main activity is called whenever application starts but i meant when the application is activated .... Suppose u r running the application and then suddenly the device got off or any how u got out of the application without stopping it properly, then when you will again start the application, obviously it will start running from the previous state before getting out of the application. When it starts again or activated, i want my background tasks to be done. Hope this time u understand what i exactly meant ......

Comment: @junaid: Then you should edit your question and include these information too.

Comment: @ Sayem Ahmed : ok, I have edited my question .... But what can be a possible solution of it? Any idea ?

Comment: @Junaid: No, I don't have any idea about that....I am pretty new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

Well - there's no such facility available in the Android SDK for you to determine whether or not your application is running - this is primarily because of the way applications are handled by Android.

For example - what would you mean by saying the application is *not running*? would that mean the UI s not visible, or the process related to the application is not running? Btw, I hope that you know that:

> Application's lifetime **!=** Application process' lifetime.

As for running background tasks, you can either make use of `AsyncTask` or the `Service` classes.

And if you're concerned about only the Application's *visible* lifetime, the you'll have to rely on making use of the `onPause` and `onResume` methods, to check on flags which you can turn on/off to capture the state of the app.

Comment: That's not entirely the case. You can track the foreground time of your application by setting flags in `onPause()` and `onResume()`. However, I agree that highlighting the `Service` class will be useful to the asker.

Comment: oh well - i was simply editing my response to put in the `onResume` and `onPause` thing when you commented :]