# how can we print The name of activity in logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

I want to Print the name of all launched Activity name on a  textView. Means If I run some activity manually e.g.

> abcActivity.class, xyxActivity.class etc.

After that I have a button when I click on it, then it print the all Activity name in the following format:

Name of Launched Activity:

> abcActivity
>
> xyxActivity .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

Button is in another Activity file...!!!

Comment: abcActivity, xyzActivity etc are from your application ? or any app. of phone ?

Comment: yes this all activity class in my Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I think :

Create a `public static ArrayList<String>` object in any one of the class so that you can use it in all other activities.

Now In `onResume()` method, check whether the className exists, if yes then dont add className in arrayListObject. Otherwise add the className of current activity in arrayListObject using add method of arrayList ie `arrayListObject.add(activityName);`.

You can get Class Name using :

#1 `this.getClass().getName();`

#2 Directly use "ABCActivity"

#3 `context.getClassName();`

Now you can use this arrayListObject to display all this values in `TextView`.

**Note :**
You will also have to take care of when the Activity1 is launching for the first time. At that time you will have to clear the arrayListObject and then have a fresh start.

For this I recommend you to go through the post : [Application Launch Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799819/android-application-launch-count)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, `onResume()` method add System.out (or) log statement `this.getClass().getName();.`

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());

(or)

Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Insdie onResume");
```

Comment: can you provide me a sample code. How we can print the name of all activity?

Comment: And how I capture the all Class name? Button is in another activity file.

Comment: As Karthink said have a static list in one of utility classes (not activity class), keep on adding all the activities you touched.

Answer (score 0):

use the log method for loggging data and printing it over logcat. You can put a line like this

Log.v(TAG,"abcActivity");

refer :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I want to print it on my textView. Not on DDMS.

Comment: well your launched activity name is just your classname..you can just use the Textview.settext(String) and pass the classname  to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`context.getClassName();` to get **activity**, **service** or **BroadcastReceiver**'s name.