# Statistics for visiting my application on google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I knew that there were a Android Developer Console, that I could check all the Statistics about my application, those statistics I've seen for now, it's all about how many times my application be installed, uninstalled, upgraded..is there any way I could know that how many people have seen my application..?

just in case if there might be something that I missed, I wrote a letter to ask Google Play Team about this question, and support said that they do not provide this kind of analytics

again, Ankit is correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

now you can find it in Google Play Developer Console

[image: User Acquisition]

[New in the Google Play Developer Console: Know where your most valuable users come from.](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/+AndroidDevelopers/albums/6187357094637098993/6187357092776174738?pid=6187357092776174738&oid=108967384991768947849)

Comment: Has this been removed? I'm sitting here thinking "Apple lets me see every stat under-the-sun for my iOS apps, but Google a Search Engine/Information Technology at its core doesn't show me ASO/SEO app store views...?" I'm speechless.

Answer (score 2):

> > is there any way I could know that how many people have seen my application..?

if you mean to say "you want to know how many times your application been viewed on Play Store!!"

Answer is >>  AFAIK **No !**

this link may be useful    [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)

If you want to know how many times user opened your application on their device after installing!!

**this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799819/android-application-launch-count) has the answer.**

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there any documentation from Google Play Store..? I think it might be a useful statistics to analyze what an application is promoted successfully or not, didn't it?

Comment: see this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/
you can actually use Google analytics to know many useful info about ur app uses.

Comment: Ankit, thank you for the link, I'll dive into this docs :)

Comment: Welcome>> after gone through it , please post your observation here too :)..

Comment: it looks like it's tracking by trigger a pageview request inside the apps, thus, as you mention, maybe there is no way to find out how many times that my apps have been viewed on Play Store, what I can think of for now is, promote my apps with a redirect link to Play Store, thus I could know the clicks..at least, some port of it..

Comment: hi all,
I want to know, how many downloads for an specific application are ? either through play store ? or is it possible. If I am developing the app, can I set an email sending option for every installation ?
I have search here in stack also, but no specific result... Do I have to make this separate question ? so one who reply this can get vote up, or its simple task to know. ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, for your question:
App installation statistics page can show you the statics, or download as CSV files, there's a brief introduction on Android Developers Site:http://goo.gl/GwqdE, as your requirement for emailing, I'm not sure Google support it or not.
if these info were not good enough for you, free feel to ask another question :)

Answer (score 1):

Google has integrated the play store and google analytics: http://analytics.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/google-play-integration.html

Comment: indeed, I do notice this feature during [Google IO 2013-What’s new for Developers in Google Play](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326455375), thank you @Oded for this update :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you right, but you can analyze how often your users open your app, where your users are located and so on with different services.

One good example for android would be [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/).

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, what I wanna know is how many times my application been viewed, thanks again:)