# How can I know how long the application has been used?

Tags: android

I would like to know how many times the user spend on my application to block or release some feature after 15min. But, I would like 15min of use and not 15min after the first launch of the app per day. I mean, I don't want to count minutes when the app is in background

I have no idea how I could do that simply, any idea ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093048/counting-how-many-times-my-android-app-has-been-opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an ActivityLifecycleCallback to your application.

1. Create a class `AppActivityLifecycleCallbacks` that `implements` `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.
2. Use this class to manage the time spent in your app.
3. In your Application class, create an instance of your `AppActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and pass it as parameter to this command: `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(myInstance)`

It is all set!