# How to get Launch count of any installed applications in API level 21 or higher?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get that how many times an application was **launched** "today".
we can use `*#*#4636#*#*` to get App usage statistics.

But in my case how i can get launch count **programmatically**.
And i think there will be no legal way to get these details.

do anyone know how to do it with any kind of Code arrangement ??

**NOTE**:: i need solution only for **API level 21(lollipop)** or higher.
for rest of the lower API level i can manage.

Comment: do you want to see the lunch count from the app?

Comment: Why not save the latest launch date/time in the SharedPreferences along with a counter? If you've already tried that and it didn't work, please explain the specific problem(s) you encountered, along with the relevant code.

Comment: @Michael i am using UsageStatsManager for getting time spent on any application with desired date or time. But here i am not getting any Launch count detail of any application.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this [Answer..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799819/application-launch-count)

You might get the solution of what you want. You can use shared Preferences or any other local database (sqlite) To save the number of times the program has been launched..

Comment: I dont think so. OP wants to get run count for any app installed in his device i guess.

Comment: That means he want to track them From his app??

Comment: @Ryan and #Shree Krishna  you are right. i want launch count for all apps installed and accordingly used.